Getting blank pdf after downloading with @react-pdf/renderer library
I have use @react-pdf/renderer library to download map in pdf.
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
import {
    PDFDownloadLink,
    Page,
    Text,
    View,
    Document,
    Image,
} from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import Link from "@/icons/Link";
   export default function Map(props: MapProps) {
    const [mapImage, setMapImage] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [isDownloading, setIsDownloading] = useState(false);
    const handlePrint = async () => {
        if (!isDownloading) {
            setIsDownloading(true);
            await handlePrintMapPDFButtonClick();
            const downloadLink = document.getElementById('pdfDownloadLink');
            if (downloadLink) {
                downloadLink.click();
            } else {
                console.error("Download link not found");
            }
            setIsDownloading(false);
        }
    };
    const handlePrintMapPDFButtonClick = async () => {
        if (mapRef.current) {
            try {
                const canvas = await html2canvas(mapRef.current.getMap().getCanvas(), {
                    useCORS: true,
            logging: true
                });
                const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                setMapImage(imgData);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error capturing map image:", error);
            }
        } else {
            console.error("Map reference is not available");
        }
    };
    const MyDocument = () => (
        <Document>
            <Page size="A4">
               {mapImage ? (
                <Image
                  src={mapImage}
                  style={{ width: "1920px", height: "590px" }} 
                />
                ) : (
                   <Text>No image available</Text>
                )}
            </Page>
        </Document>
    );

    return (
        <DeckGL
            layers={layers}
            views={mapView}
        >
            <ReactMap
                ref={mapRef}
                mapboxAccessToken={import.meta.env.VITE_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
                mapLib={import("mapbox-gl")}
                reuseMaps
                mapStyle={getMapboxMapStyle(theme.palette.mode === "dark", props.style)}
                projection={{ name: "mercator" }}
                onLoad={onRender}
            />

            <button style={{ position: "absolute", top: "20rem" }} onClick={handlePrint}>
                Download PDF
                <PDFDownloadLink
                    id="pdfDownloadLink"
                    document={<MyDocument />}
                    fileName="map.pdf"
                    style={{ display: 'none', height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                >
                    <Link />
                </PDFDownloadLink>
            </button>

        </DeckGL>
    );

1] I had tried pass the proper token to got the map.
2] Log the mapImage here I got the response too when i Copy response and paste in new tab so on this tab             also show the blank page.
3] My expectation is when user download the pdf so it's not show the blank pdf instead of it shows the map image in downloaded pdf.
